# Using foursquare authentication

Tags: authentication, foursquare

So I'm making an app where I use foursquare API to get closest venues. I'm also thinking about using the features that require the user to authenticate, like check in endpoint. But as I have explored the foursquare authentication, it seems like that my users would have to create foursquare account to use my app.

My problem with this is that it feels like I'm giving too big part of my app (all the user details) to foursquare's side. Like if I want to create features in my app that don't require foursquare account, isn't the linkage to foursquare's stuff restricting my ability to grow my app (as my users are basically all foursquare's users.)

So is there a way to create my own user database while using the foursquare's features? Or is this even a thing to take into account? Will it cause me problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The checkin endpoint requires user authentication because a user is checking into a venue. This is key feature of foursquare. The user has to be a foursquare user because there'd be no other way for foursquare to track them and stats, and comments, etc.

I think what you want to do is create your own app that allows someone to do things similar to Swarm or some of the venue features in Foursquare. You need to create your own database of user information and track everything yourself. If a person wants to use any of foursquare features they need to be a foursquare user. Anything your app keeps track of wont be a part of the foursquare network. One could not checkin with your app and have it show up in foursquare, if you keep things separate.

If you decide to mix and match just remember there are time limits on data caching that foursquare would like you to adhere to.

As for future problems, read the Terms Of Service for the API carefully, and if your app seems like a clone of either Swarm or FourSquare, and you're not using their users, they might ask you to cease and desist